# Html drag and drop without ID

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

in this demo: http://www.netmagazine.com/files/tutorials/demos/2013/01/create-drag-and-drop-features-in-html5/demo/demo.html
you'll see that you can move items using drag and drop.
The code to do this is pretty straightforward:

```
  function dragUser(user, event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData('User', user.id);
} 
function dropUser(target, event) {
  var user = event.dataTransfer.getData('User');
  target.appendChild(document.getElementById(user));
}
```

What it's doing is it stores an id of an element and then finds that id in dom and moves it by using appendChild.
The problem I experience is that I have elements that do not have Ids.

```
<span class=".myClass">item</span>
```

So, I have no way to uniquely identify an element, so I'm not sure how to move element.

Comment: New browsers have `getElementsByClassName` but you may have to sort through the list returned to find the right one. jQuery or other framework has to be mentioned here as it can find elements many ways.

Comment: id attribute is a unique possible, would be ideal, but you can create a style class or something that differentiates as a name. is not recommended and will be far more confusing

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just add unique ids to your elements?

Comment: @LeeMeador, I just have too many duplicated elements, there's no way I can uniquely distinguish those

Comment: You could make up a unique id and attach it to the element at the start of the drag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not actually need an id, any identifier that can be expressed as a string will do (this is because `getData`/`setData` only work with string values). And if there is nothing already there you can simply make something up. Here we have an array of elements that allows associating an element (which cannot be represented as a string) with its index in the array (which can):

```
var elements = [];

function dragUser(element, event) {
    var index = elements.indexOf(element);
    if (index == -1) {
        // not already existing in the array, add it now
        elements.push(element);
        index = elements.length - 1;
    }

    event.dataTransfer.setData('index', index);
} 

function dropUser(target, event) {
    var element = elements[event.dataTransfer.getData('index')];
    target.appendChild(element);
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/nR4YW/)**.

This code uses [`Array.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which means no IE < 9, but that's a technical detail that can be easily worked around.

Comment: Thank Jon. This is super cool. I've spent a while trying to pass the whole object to dropUser, but this solution works great.

Comment: Haha, the ninja turtles.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where you don't have id's, we can dynamically create and id for that dragabble element and after dropping that in target element, we have to remove that id value. This scenario worked for me.

```
taskItem.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
event.target.id = "taskid";
event.dataTransfer.setData("taskItem", event.target.id);
```

}, false);

and drop handler is

```
taskView.addEventListener('drop', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("taskItem");
        var element = document.getElementById(data);
        event.target.appendChild(element);
        element.removeAttribute('id');
    }, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

try to log the event in the dropUser function
and search for the (event.target||event.srcElement).that is what u need.

```
        function dropUser(target, event) {
console.log(event)
          var user = event.dataTransfer.getData('User');
          target.appendChild(event.target||event.srcElement);
        }
```